# ASP.NET MVC: issues in validation and data formating when submit list of items

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new on ASP.NET MVC, I need your help. I have list of items and I want to edit both of them at the same times.

My problem is when I using annotation to format display and editing data, I can't submit my form because the input data is not valid.

The code I using on the metadata class to format data here:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<decimal> amount { get; set; } 
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
```

But when I create new form to submit **only one item**, I don't have any validation message.
Why it's difference between submit 1 item and submit multiple items?

Here is my razor code to generate the list

```
@model PTT_WEBSITE.Areas.RM.Models.MonthlyInvoice
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="no">No</th>
        <th>Payment item</th>
        <th width="150">Price</th>
        <th width="100">Old number</th>
        <th width="100">New number</th>
        <th width="100">Quantity</th>
        <th width="150">Amount</th>
        <th width="50"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    @for(int i = 0; i< Model.MonthlyFees.Count; i++) {
    <tr id="payment_item_@i" >
        <td>@i</td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.MonthlyFees[i].name)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.MonthlyFees[i].paymentitemcode)
             @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.MonthlyFees[i].name)
             @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.MonthlyFees[i].isfixed)
             @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.MonthlyFees[i].ismultiple)
        </td>
        <td  class="align-right"> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MonthlyFees[i].price) </td>
        <td class="align-right">@Html.EditorFor(x => x.MonthlyFees[i].fromnumber)</td>
        <td class="align-right"> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MonthlyFees[i].tonumber) </td>
        <td class="align-right"> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MonthlyFees[i].quantity) </td>
        <td  class="align-right"> @Html.EditorFor(x => x.MonthlyFees[i].amount, new { @ReadOnly = "ReadOnly" }) </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#" onclick ="deleteitem(@i)"><i class="delete fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.MonthlyFees[i].isdeleted)
        </td>

    </tr>
    }       
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
        <td colspan ="6" align="right">Tổng cộng: </td>
        <td class="align-right">@String.Format("{0:#,###}",totalAmount)</td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
}
```

controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(MonthlyInvoice invoice)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //...
            }
            //...
            return View( invoice);
        }
```

Message:

- The value '70,000' is not valid for amount.
- The value '70,000' is not valid for price.
- The value '1,700,000' is not valid for amount.
- The value '1,700,000' is not valid for price.

The decimal number not allows the commas (,). I try to remove all commas inside the number and submit again, it works fine.
But The value '1,700,000' when I submit it on a form to edit only 1 item, the value is accepted, when I make form to submit a list of items it isn't accept.

My screen
https://www.dropbox.com/s/eagvk4uuu2wabds/problems.PNG?dl=0

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Post the code for your view and how you generate the list

Comment: A bit hard to understand what you're asking. You can't submit your form when using `DisplayFormat`, but works when you're not using it? What does your `@Model` look like? How are you creating your `<form>`?

Comment: You must be doing something different with the other form, and if that's the one causing the problem, you should include the code in your question

Comment: Did you change the culture of your application ? it seems you are using localization in your application.

Comment: I don't using localization in my application. This view have been modified by me for easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your model (with list) to json  in javascpript and post to action using $.ajax. when you get json string in action, convert to model, and use ModelState.IsValid

Comment: Now, I don't want to use ajax on this project. I just implement basic feature of asp.net mvc to insert, update data. I need to know about validation feature of asp.net mvc. Can you suggest me some documents or link to learn about that.